# Why doesn't this CSS get scoped by vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

Inside a Vue single file component I have a scoped style section that looks like this:

```
<style scoped>
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #suggestions, #form, #mapcontainer, #searchcontainer {
        width: 100%; padding: 6px;
    }
    #mapcontainer div#mapx {
        height: 400px
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #workarea {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
    }
    #mapcontainer {
        grid-column: 1;
    }
    .blurb {
        grid-column: 2;
        margin-left: 12px;
    }

    #mapcontainer div#mapx {
        height:600px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

#suggestions tr { border-bottom: thin solid silver;  }
#suggestions td { padding: 6px 3px 6px 3px }
#suggestions table { margin-bottom: 12px }
</style>
```

After checking the rendered source in Chrome's inspector I see the `data` tag in the rendered component like this:

```
<div data-s-0="" id="appspace">
```

but I don't see any of the expected changes to the CSS as documented [in the section about scoped CSS in the vue.js docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html)

It seems to happen every time the scoped style contains a `@media` query.

What do I need to change so that styles stay scoped?

Comment: You have declared ```<style scoped>``` in your style tag. If you don't want your CSS rules to apply to only the template they are declared in, remove the scoped attribute.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader/issues/42) describe the issue you have?

Comment: @raina77ow - yes, it does. Has it been fixed (I'm not familiar with the process so I can't tell - my ignorance, forgive that)

Comment: @simone That's actually weird. [PR](https://github.com/rubenbrieva/http-vue-loader/commit/42a49ac61e7f8ba2eabe763f479e943902f8023c) for this issue was commented with notice that the solution provided doesn't work in Edge - with a fix. But somehow that fix wasn't applied, and I assume the PR was never merged. You might consider adding a separate PR for that issue.

Comment: Weird. Works well on this little example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-jepsen-c50uf?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue (pink bacground when you narrow the browser)

Comment: @Renaud - the issue isn't that the CSS doesn't work, the issue is that it isn't scoped, and therefore the CSS "leaks" to other components

Comment: @tomerpacific - I do want the rules to stay scoped - the issue is that they do not, and the CSS of the component styles other components as well

Comment: Rules are scoped on my codesandbox example at least, generated CSS is: 
`@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
#suggestions[data-v-763db97b] {
    background: pink;
}
}`. Well, it doesn't mean there is no issue on setup tho.

Comment: @Renaud - ok, I tried removing the at-media parts, and actually it doesn't stay scoped either; I guess it is indeed something else

Comment: If you could set-up a minimal reproduction that would maybe help (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)